# Dojo 1.8 add new row

Tags: dojo

I am adding a new row to EnhancedGrid with IndirectSelection and FilterPlugin enabled. The code to add new row is:

```
grid.store.newItem({msConstId: response, msname: msName,description:description, msorder:msorder,eventType:eventTypeVal,eventTypeId:eventTypeId,isngrp:'N',eventAttribute:eventAttributeVal,eventAttributeId:eventAttribute});
grid.store.fetch();
```

This creates a new row but that is hidden and not visible and is present outside the border of grid. I had to use Firebug to verify  that it has been created. This new row is not visible. I checked html code for a visible row with new row and there is no difference in code.

What could be the possible cause?

Comment: `grid.store.fetch()` has no effect, call `grid.render()` instead

Comment: Thanks a lot. That worked. Can you put it as answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you wish :)

grid.store.fetch() has no effect, call grid.render() - this will rerender the table markup with currently loaded store / itemset